# getting and using TestNG @test annotation parameters

Tags: java, selenium, testing, annotations, testng

I want to use testName, suiteName & description that are specified in `@Test` annotation in `@BeforeMethod`, but could not find anywhere a way to do so. I would appreciate your help.

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod() throws Exception {
    initTest(testName here, suiteName here, description here);
}

@Test(testName = "Test Name", suiteName = "Suite Name", description = "Description")
public void Test01() throws Exception {
    //test code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tries this way

```java
@Test(testName = "my test", suiteName = "my suite", description = "my description")
public void test(ITestContext tContext){
    System.out.println(tContext.getName());
    System.out.println(tContext.getSuite().getName());
}
```

But this returns default values in some reason. However below (not very elegant way) is working:

```java
@BeforeMethod
public void printData(Method method){
    System.out.println(method.getAnnotation(Test.class).testName());
    System.out.println(method.getAnnotation(Test.class).suiteName());
    System.out.println(method.getAnnotation(Test.class).description());
}

@Test(testName = "my test", suiteName = "my suite", description = "my description")
public void test(){
    // Test code
}
```

So that you can extract the values you need in `@BeforeMethod` and use them withing your test.